# Weighted average per day from inconsistent seconds data for each id in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which is indexed by with inconsistent datetime objects. I have seen similar examples where values can be averaged per day, but not the average per day for each id. I could create a new data frame for each selection_id but i assume there is a better way that i just cant find online.

In the data frame i have is:

```
                                             | selection_id  | price           |
                                             | ------------- | --------------- |
                    |2023-05-13 05:57:07.554 | 1             | 1.50            |
                    |2023-05-13 06:08:59.193 | 1             | 1.56            |
                    |2023-05-13 06:08:59.085 | 1             | 1.61            |
                    |2023-05-13 06:08:59.085 | 1             | 1.50            |
                    |2023-05-13 06:08:59.085 | 1             | 1.51            |
                    |2023-05-13 06:08:59.085 | 45            | 3.12            |
                    |2023-05-13 05:57:07.554 | 45            | 3.16            |
                    |2023-05-13 06:08:59.193 | 45            | 3.12            |
                    |2023-05-13 06:08:59.085 | 45            | 3.16            |
                    |2023-05-13 06:08:59.085 | 45            | 3.12            |
                    |2023-05-13 06:08:59.085 | 98            | 7.05            |
                    |2023-05-13 06:08:59.085 | 98            | 7.52            |
                    |2023-05-13 05:57:07.554 | 98            | 7.11            |
                    |2023-05-13 06:08:59.193 | 98            | 7.99            |
                    |2023-05-13 06:08:59.085 | 98            | 7.50            |
                    |2023-05-13 06:08:59.085 | 98            | 7.20            |
                    |2023-05-13 06:08:59.085 | 98            | 7.65            |
                    |2023-05-13 06:08:59.085 | 98            | 7.45            |
                    |2023-05-14 05:57:07.554 | 1             | 2.50            |
                    |2023-05-14 06:08:59.193 | 1             | 2.56            |
                    |2023-05-14 06:08:59.085 | 1             | 2.61            |
                    |2023-05-14 06:08:59.085 | 1             | 2.50            |
                    |2023-05-14 06:08:59.085 | 1             | 2.51            |
                    |2023-05-14 06:08:59.085 | 45            | 2.12            |
                    |2023-05-14 05:57:07.554 | 45            | 2.16            |
                    |2023-05-14 06:08:59.193 | 45            | 2.12            |
                    |2023-05-14 06:08:59.085 | 45            | 2.16            |
                    |2023-05-14 06:08:59.085 | 45            | 2.12            |
                    |2023-05-14 06:08:59.085 | 98            | 7.05            |
                    |2023-05-14 06:08:59.085 | 98            | 7.52            |
                    |2023-05-14 05:57:07.554 | 98            | 7.11            |
                    |2023-05-14 06:08:59.193 | 98            | 7.99            |
                    |2023-05-14 06:08:59.085 | 98            | 7.50            |
                    |2023-05-14 06:08:59.085 | 98            | 7.20            |
                    |2023-05-14 06:08:59.085 | 98            | 7.65            |
                    |2023-05-14 06:08:59.085 | 98            | 7.45            |
```

And i want to summerise the data frame to:

```
                                             | selection_id   | price            |
                                             | -------------- | ---------------- |
                    |2023-05-13              | 1              | 1.536            |
                    |2023-05-13              | 45             | 3.136            |
                    |2023-05-13              | 98             | 7.434            |
                    |2023-05-14              | 1              | 2.536            |
                    |2023-05-14              | 45             | 2.136            |
                    |2023-05-14              | 98             | 7.434            |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
out = (
    df.groupby([pd.to_datetime(df.index).date, #or df.index.date if it's a DatetimeIndex
                "selection_id"])["price"].mean().reset_index(level=1)
      )
```

Output :

```
print(out)

           selection_id  price
2023-05-13            1   1.54
2023-05-13           45   3.14
2023-05-13           98   7.43
2023-05-14            1   2.54
2023-05-14           45   2.14
2023-05-14           98   7.43
```

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the date without the time, you can utilize `dt.date`. Then use `groupby` to group the data by `date` and `selection id`, after that, apply `agg` to compute the mean for each group.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

summary_df = df.groupby([df['datetime'].dt.date, 'selection_id']).agg({'price': 'mean'}).reset_index()

summary_df.head()
```